# Is Netty handler unique for each connection?

Tags: java, netty

I've been looking over at the proxy server example from [Netty website](http://static.netty.io/3.5/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/proxy/HexDumpProxyInboundHandler.html):

The example source code handler has a volatile variable

```
private volatile Channel outboundChannel;
```

which takes care of the channel that connects to another server for proxy.

This got me to wonder if this is the correct and safe way to implement for multiple connections for proxy.

I would like to allow multiple connections(inbound) to connect to different outbounds, while making sure that every inbound connection is uniquely linked to the outbound channel.

According to my knowledge, Netty generates a new pipeline for each connection. Does this mean a newly generated handler by pipeline factory is uniquely dedicated to the new connection(channel)?

p.s. If I have 1,000 active connections to my Netty server, does this mean there are 1,000 different pipelines?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is one pipeline created per connection, but the pipeline may contain both shared and exclusive handlers. Some handlers do not keep state and a single instance can be inserted into multiple [all] pipelines. Netty provided handlers that can be shared are annotated with [ChannelHandler.Sharable](http://netty.io/3.6/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelHandler.Sharable.html). See the section titled **Shared and Exclusive Channel Handlers** in this [tutorial](http://seeallhearall.blogspot.com/2012/06/netty-tutorial-part-15-on-channel.html).

Comment: Right, but if I declare an exclusive channel handler for each connection (that is each pipeline), does that mean that channel handler is dedicated to that specific connection only?

Comment: Correct. You could reimplement a given handler to be Sharable by keeping all state in attachments or ChannelLocals.

Comment: I concern about the resources collection problem. 
How can I release the handler resource after use?

Comment: Any idea why the built-in [HTTP handlers are not sharable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58531825/should-all-netty-http-handlers-be-shared)? With a moderately loaded HTTP server this would get heavy on the GC.